# How to switch to a specific tab panel on click of a particular link using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have a tab panel using jQuery and everything works properly, except the link with `data-anchor` inside a tab content that should be switch to a specific tab. The tab switching is working but the tab content is not displayed.

How to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-panels">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active" rel="panel1">panel1</li>
    <li rel="panel2" id="custpanel2">panel2</li>
    <li rel="panel3">panel3</li>
    <li rel="panel4">panel4</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="panel active" id="panel1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <a href="custpanel2" data-anchor="#custpanel2">
      Click here
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.tab-panels .tabs li').on('click', function(){
  var $panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');

  $panel.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var panelToShow = $(this).attr('rel');

  $panel.find('.panel.active').fadeOut(300, showNextPanel);

  function showNextPanel(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');

    $('#'+panelToShow).fadeIn(300, function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
    })
  }
});

//Link inside tab content
$('[data-anchor="#custpanel2"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');

    $panel.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.tabs li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');

    var panelToShow = $(this).attr('rel');


    $panel.find('.panel.active').fadeOut(300, showNextPanel);

    function showNextPanel(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');

      $('#'+panelToShow).fadeIn(300, function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess you made mistake in your showNextPanel() function.

Comment: what's error? can you please help me out?

Comment: Try below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var panelToShow = $(this).attr('rel');
value of panelToShow  is retrived from attirbute named "**rel**" and the link don't have "**rel**" attribute you can fix the problem without modifying the logic 
e.g.

> rel="panel1"

Comment: do you mean instead of `a href="custpanel2" data-anchor="#custpanel2"` it should be `a href="panel3" rel="panel3"`? inside tab content?

Comment: Exactly ad the JavaScript code is looking for value of "rel" for the clicked element on the basis of value respective tab is displayed data-anchore value also should be there as your code is binding click event on using that as selector

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is not getting correct element inside the function I guess, So please use below code.

```
function showNextPanel(){
    $('.tab-panels div.panel').removeClass('active');

    $('#'+panelToShow).fadeIn(300, function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$('[data-anchor="#custpanel2"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');

    $panel.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.tabs li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');

    var panelToShow = $(this).attr('href');


    $panel.find('.panel.active').fadeOut(300, showNextPanel);

    function showNextPanel(){
      $('.tab-panels div.panel').removeClass('active');

      $('#'+panelToShow).fadeIn(300, function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
      })
    }
});
```

Comment: I encountered same issue. When the a href clicked inside tab content, the tab is switching but the tab content is not displayed.